# How to turn a Nest or Nest-E thermostat to completely off (no power, no battery)?

Tags: hvac, nest, battery

Is it possible to remove the battery, or otherwise turn a Nest thermostat completely off, for times when there is no power to the furnace?  This is to avoid draining the battery in the Nest completely, as that's generally regarded as bad for battery life.

Answer (score 2):

There is not. They're pretty easy to pop off, so I just pull mine off and plug the back into a standard Micro USB charger.